# Saving Table in database using a ViewModel database-first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I had an MVC application to update a table in a database, but now I needed to add a ViewModel so that I could have the multiple tables displaying on a view page.  But the problem now is that it will not save into the database now. I am using database first approach (not code-first).

Here is what I have so far:

In my ViewModel:

```
Public Class ClientUserProjectIssue
    Public Property uTable As UserTable
    Public Property issueType As IssueTypeTable
    Public Property IssueTable As IssueTable
End Class
```

In the view:

```
@ModelType IssueTracker.ClientUserProjectIssue

@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.IssueTable.IssueSummary)
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.IssueTable.IssueDescription)
```

In my controller:

```
Public Function UpdateIssue(issue As IssueTracker.ClientUserProjectIssue, objModelMail As IssueTable, command As String) As ActionResult

dbServer.Entry(issue).State = EntityState.Modified
dbServer.SaveChanges()
```

I will now get a null value because I am using the ViewModel instead of a single table.

I was trying to implement something like this:

```
Using context As New DbContext()
    Dim dataModel As DatabaseEntities= context.IssueEntiteis.where(Function(x) x.Id = viewModel.Id).First()
    dataModel.Name = viewModel.Name
    dataModel.Type = viewModel.Type
    context.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

But I was getting errors so I am pretty sure I can't do it that way because I am using database first, how can I implement a viewModel so that I can save tables in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the ViewModel to the DbContext.Entry method.

Instead of passing the ViewModel,
you should pass the property of the ViewModel.

```
dbServer.Entry(issue.uTable).State = EntityState.Modified;
```